# Creating, Drawing Lines and saving bitmap gives Generic GDI+ error

Tags: c#, image, winforms, bitmap

I have a very simple method that takes a signature as a list of points and draws them as lines on a bitmap. And I want to take that bitmap and save it to a file, but when I call the Save method Im getting "A generic error occured in GDI+" and no Inner Exception.

This seems like pretty straight forward code so Im not sure what the problem is.

```
using (var b = new Bitmap(width, height))
{
    var g = Graphics.FromImage(b);
    var lastPoint = points[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < points.Length; i++)
    {
        var p = points[i];
        // When the user takes the pen off the device, X/Y is set to -1
        if ((lastPoint.X >= 0 || lastPoint.Y >= 0) && (p.X >= 0 || p.Y >= 0))
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, lastPoint.X, lastPoint.Y, p.X, p.Y);
        lastPoint = p;
    }
    g.Flush();
    pictureBox.Image = b;
    b.Save("C:\\test.bmp");
}
```

I've tried saving with all the possible ImageFormats, put the graphics object in a using statement, and as a long shot I even tried:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    b.Save(ms, ImageFormats.Bmp); // And b.Save(ms, ImageFormats.MemoryBmp);
    Image.FromStream(ms).Save("C:\\test.bmp");
}
```

The strange thing is, if I remove the b.Save (or ignore the exception), the pictureBox displays the image perfectly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible you don't have write access to that location?

Comment: Where is the g getting declared?  Try disposing that before you save it.  Saving to the root drive isn't a good location — Windows will probably fight you with security issues.

Comment: Sorry I forgot the graphic declaration, I edited my question. Im writing to the root just for testing purposes, but I do have full write access.

Comment: Well, you shouldn't have full write access to that since that's considered OS territory.  Try a different path anyway.

Comment: You shouldn't have that bitmap in a using block since the PictureBox is trying to use it.

Comment: Not the `Bitmap` but the `Graphic` object should live in the using block!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has two issues, one hiding the other:

- Your application probably doesn't have writing rights on the root of `C:`, so the `Save` fails.
- You also can't have a `PictureBox` display a `Bitmap` which you then destroy in the `using` block.

So you should change the code to something like this:

```
var b = new Bitmap(width, height);

using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
{
    var lastPoint = points[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < points.Length; i++)
    {
        var p = points[i];
        // When the user takes the pen off the device, X/Y is set to -1
        if ((lastPoint.X >= 0 || lastPoint.Y >= 0) && (p.X >= 0 || p.Y >= 0))
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, lastPoint.X, lastPoint.Y, p.X, p.Y);
        lastPoint = p;
    }
    // g.Flush(); not necessary
    pictureBox1.Image = b;
    b.Save("C:\\temp\\test.bmp");
}
```

You also should include a check on the `Length` of the array and consider using a `List<Points>` instead, also checking its `Count` and using `DrawLines`  on `points.ToArray()` for better line joins, especially with thick, semi-transparent lines!

Comment: I assumed since I am able to create/modify files on my root that applications had write access as well, I also assumed I would get an access denied exception if that was the case. Lesson learned on that one. I also removed the using from the bitmap and added it to the Graphics declaration, thank you for the insight.

Comment: Also, Im not using DrawLines because some of the points have -1 as the X/Y to indicate the pen was removed from the pad

Comment: As for DrawLines: with opaque or thin lines it doesn't matter much; I usually use a `List<List>Point>>` to hold several sequences of lines or curves; for most natural looks `DrawCurves` works even better..

Answer (score 2):

I would draw to the `PictureBox` using the corresponding `Graphics` from the `Paint` event and then save to a bitmap:

```
    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        MyDrawing(e.Graphics);

        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
        pictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(b, pictureBox1.ClientRectangle);
        b.Save(@"C:\test.bmp");

    }
    private void MyDrawing(Graphics g)
    {
        var lastPoint = points[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < points.Count; i++)
        {
            var p = points[i];
            // When the user takes the pen off the device, X/Y is set to -1
            if ((lastPoint.X >= 0 || lastPoint.Y >= 0) && (p.X >= 0 || p.Y >= 0))
                g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, lastPoint.X, lastPoint.Y, p.X, p.Y);
            lastPoint = p;
        }
        g.Flush();
    }
```

[image]

Saved BMP:

[image]